Where to find custom beamer templates?
I would like to create an original Beamer template and for this I am looking for original templates that already exist. If you know or have any example sites, I would like to access them please.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Note that this is English speaking Forum, please translate it

Si vous préférez poser la question en français : https://texnique.fr/osqa/

thanks everyone for the answer :)
